# Как с помощью FastMM4 исправлять утечку памяти?

Tags: delphi

Вставил `LogMemoryManagerStateToFile();`

[В конец события FormOnCreate](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9q8YloAuwL8UGJldUl6TXA4RjQ)

[В конец constructor: Объект 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9q8YloAuwL8b3ZIc0NjMXR4aGc)

[В конец constructor: Объект 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9q8YloAuwL8UVlzSFh3QTBwWTA)

[Server11_MemoryManager_EventLog.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9q8YloAuwL8SWEtbkhQbW02anM)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так у вас прямо на скриншоте написано - детальная информация сохранена в текстовом файле рядом с приложением. Открываете его, там полный текст - что в какой последовательности вызывалось при создании той или иной утечки. Т.е. из файла вы понимаете, когда и где память была выделена. Остается только придумать, где вам написать код освобождения этой памяти. Рекомендуется начинать с самых больших объектов, например  - TFDQuery, поскольку подавляющее большинство мелких - это "внутренности" больших. Устранив большое автоматом убирается мелкое.

Comment: @kami я в этом тексте не ориентируюсь, и не понимаю пока что надо сделать, если можно 1 пример

Comment: @kami "Т.е. из файла вы понимаете" как понять, можно один пример из файла разобрать?

Answer (score 1):

То что вы видите в отчете - это классы объектов и их количества, которые были созданы и не были освобождены. Занимаемая ими память "утекла".

Смотрите от больших к меньшим, т.к. более крупные, обычно, включают в себя более мелкие. Начните с `TFDQuery` - посмотрите где и сколько раз он создается, и где/почему не освобождается.

Comment: То есть, все утечки в списке это я что то создал и не уничтожил?

Comment: В списке это все что вы создали и не уничтожили. Да.